# How to change indexes and columns of a dataframe created from a dictionary without NAN values getting displayed?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df_dict = {'k1':(1,2,3),'k2':(20,30,40),'k3':(30,40,50),'k4':[100,200,300]}

data_Frame_dict = pd.DataFrame(data=df_dict,index=['k11','k22','k33'],columns=['s1','s2','s3','s4'])

data_Frame_dict

     s1   s2   s3   s4
k11  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
k22  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
k33  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

this makes all data in the dataframe NAN. how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing a dictionary, the `columns` argument is used to select the keys from the dictionary to use as columns. To see what I mean, here is an example:

```
pd.DataFrame(df_dict, columns=['k1', 'k4'])

   k1   k4
0   1  100
1   2  200
2   3  300
```

If your passed column values are not present in the dictionary, then the column is inserted as a column full of NaNs. As another example, see

```
pd.DataFrame(df_dict, columns=['k1', 'k4', 'dummy_col'])

   k1   k4 dummy_col
0   1  100       NaN
1   2  200       NaN
2   3  300       NaN
```

---

What you can do is use the original column names and then rename them as a second step.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_dict, index=['k11','k22','k33']) 
df.columns = ['s1','s2','s3','s4']
```

Keep in mind that the column ordering may not necessary reflect the actual column ordering, because it depends on whether your implementation of python supports ordered dictionaries or not (spoiler alert, it is only supported on 3.6+).

What I suggest is

```
col_mapping = {'k1': 's1', 'k2': 's2', ...}
df = (pd.DataFrame(data=df_dict, index=['k11','k22','k33'])
        .rename(col_mapping, axis=1))
```